# Python: how to convert a list of dictionary to a geopandas dataframe?

Tags: python

I have list of dictionary that looks like the following

```
myList:

[{'properties': {'raster_val': 159.6666717529297},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[(0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.016648035783361492, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165)]]}},
 {'properties': {'raster_val': 176.6071014404297},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[(0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.033296071566722985, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.033296071566722985, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165)]]}}]
```

I would like a pandas datafame like the following

```
df
      raster_val            geometry
0   159.6666717529297     POLYGON(0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165), (0.016648035783361492, 5.801840470501484),(0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484),(0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),(0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165)
1   176.6071014404297     POLYGON(0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),(0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484), (0.033296071566722985, 5.801840470501484),(0.033296071566722985, 5.810164488393165),(0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it like:

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

data = [{'properties': {'raster_val': 159.6666717529297},
         'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
                      'coordinates': [[(0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165),
                                       (0.016648035783361492, 5.801840470501484),
                                       (0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484),
                                       (0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),
                                       (0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165)]]}},
        {'properties': {'raster_val': 176.6071014404297},
         'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
                      'coordinates': [[(0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),
                                       (0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484),
                                       (0.033296071566722985, 5.801840470501484),
                                       (0.033296071566722985, 5.810164488393165),
                                       (0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165)]]}}]

parsed_data = [[item['properties']['raster_val'],
                Polygon(item['geometry']['coordinates'][0])] for item in data]
print(pd.DataFrame(data=parsed_data, columns=['raster_val', 'geometry']))
```

Output:

```
   raster_val                                           geometry
0  159.666672  POLYGON ((0.01664803578336149 5.81016448839316...
1  176.607101  POLYGON ((0.02497205367504218 5.81016448839316...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly how you want the coordinates to be stored in the geometry column.

In the following code I've used `geometry` from `shapely` to convert them to a `POLYGON`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from shapely import geometry

mylist = [{'properties': {'raster_val': 159.6666717529297},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[(0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.016648035783361492, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.016648035783361492, 5.810164488393165)]]}},
 {'properties': {'raster_val': 176.6071014404297},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[(0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.033296071566722985, 5.801840470501484),
     (0.033296071566722985, 5.810164488393165),
     (0.024972053675042183, 5.810164488393165)]]}}]

mydic = {poly['properties']['raster_val']: geometry.Polygon(poly['geometry']['coordinates'][0]) for poly in mylist}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydic, orient='index').reset_index()

df.columns = ['raster_val','geometry']

print(df)

   raster_val                                           geometry
0  159.666672  POLYGON ((0.01664803578336149 5.81016448839316...
1  176.607101  POLYGON ((0.02497205367504218 5.81016448839316...
```

Comment: I would like the coordinates to be stored as `POLYGON` for a `geopandas`dataframe

Comment: I've updated the code to store the coordinates as POLYGON. Unfortunately I'm having trouble installing geopandas so can't post code to convert the data frame to a GeoDataFrame, if that's what you are trying to do.